# Number of attempts required to increment a counter based on probability of success

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a counting variable C that gets incremented every time a particular condition is met.  Let's call this a "successful attempt."

Suppose also that I have a non-linear function F() expressing the probability of an attempt being successful as a decimal value on the range [0.0, 1.0].  The value of F() is a function of the counter variable C.  In other words, the higher the value of C, the lower the probability that C will be incremented.

Example:  C = 0.  I evaluate the probability function and determine that I have an X% chance of success.  I get a random number (roll the dice) and based on the value of the dice roll I either fail or succeed.  If I fail, C stays at 0.  If I succeed, then C gets incremented by 1.  Assuming I succeed, C = 1 and P(success) is now < X%.

I hope this makes sense.

It's been years since I've taken stats in university, and googling hasn't turned up any fruitful results.  **Is it possible to calculate the expected number of attempts/dice rolls needed in order to raise the counter variable from 0 to some arbitary value N?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the probability of success when the counter is incremented to $C$ is $F(C)$, the mean number of attempts required to reach the $k+1$th counter once the $k$th counter has been reached $\frac{1}{F(C)}$, and the answer is therefore $\displaystyle \sum_{C=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{F(C)}$.

Comment: Interesting, thank you.  If F is continuous, I should be able to integrate it dC, correct?